# Conditionally apply gradient color to dataframe cells based on values from another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this.  I would like to apply a conditional color to the cells in column "col" based on their corresponding value in column "prb".  The image on the right is where I'm at so far, but I cannot seem to get a "gradient" to work.

[image]
[image]

The code below "works", and the problem is that c1 is explicitly defined as 'background-color: red'.  But it really needs to be a conditional that applies a color map based on the values in 'prb.'.  I suspect that is a much easier way to do this.

```
def select_col(x):
    c1 = 'background-color: red'
    c2 = '' 
    #compare columns
    mask = abs(x['prb']) > 0
    #DataFrame with same index and columns names as original filled empty strings
    df1 =  pd.DataFrame(c2, index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    #modify values of df1 column by boolean mask
    df1.loc[mask, 'col'] = c1
    return df1

df.style.apply(select_col, axis=None)
```

This is another "almost working" method.  However, note how the numbers are colored, but not the words - which is the goal.  I also couldn't figure out how to get this seemingly easier approach to work.   Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import seaborn as sns
cm = sns.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True)
s = df.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm)
s
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, perhaps someone can find a more pythonic solution?

```
def select_col(x):
   c1 = 'background-color: red'
   c3 = 'background-color: blue'
   c2 = '' 
   #compare columns
   mask = x['E'] > .5
   mask2 = x['E'] < .5
   #DataFrame with same index and columns names as original filled empty strings
   df1 =  pd.DataFrame(c2, index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
   #modify values of df1 column by boolean mask
   df1.loc[mask, 'A'] = c1
   df1.loc[mask2, 'A'] = c3
   return df1

df.style.apply(select_col, axis=None)
```